# Not able to get session object attribute value correctly from controller class in my filter class

Tags: java, session, filter, controller, httprequest

I'm working with a java Filter class and I'm not able to get my session object from my controller class into my Filter so I can check its boolean value and execute code. I need to check that the session attribute "authorized" is equal to true. If so redirect to index.jsp, rather than login.html.

The controller class:

public class AuthController extends HttpServlet {

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // Hardcoded for simplicity. A real world application would get these from a database.
    String username = "librarian";
    String password =  "sesame";

    String suppliedUsername = request.getParameter("username");
    String suppliedPassword = request.getParameter("password");

     boolean authorized = false;
    if (suppliedUsername != null
            && suppliedUsername.equals(username)
            && suppliedPassword != null
            && suppliedPassword.equals(password)) {
        authorized = true;
    }

    if (authorized == true) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("authorized", true);
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("loginfailed.html");
    }
}
```

The Filter class:

public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

```
private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

   chain.doFilter(request, response);

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;


    boolean authorized = Boolean.TRUE == request.getAttribute("authorized");
   //test authorized value
   System.out.println(authorized);
    if (authorized == false){

        httpResponse.sendRedirect("login.html");

    }
     if (authorized == true) {

        httpResponse.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

    }
```

When I debug my authorized value is always ending up false, even when I login with valid credentials. My issue seems to be on this line:

```
    boolean authorized = Boolean.TRUE == request.getAttribute("authorized");
   //test authorized value
   System.out.println(authorized);
```

Comment: Try: `boolean authorized = Boolean.TRUE.equals(request.getAttribute("authorized"));`

Comment: I tried the suggested change but see no change in the value.